# match against template template type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-systems

Say I would like to type-match any container with a specific member (a constraint) - but also bind type variables to both the container and the member. For example let `T` and `U` be the template type variables corresponding to class and member `Someclass.member`. Is this possible?

Let's simplify things by templating the container. This moves the member type into the type system as the template type parameter which allows removing the constraint. Now can I bind the type variables to both the template type and the template type parameter? For example let `T` and `U` be the template type variables corresponding to the templated container `T<U>`. Is this possible?

For example,

```
template <typename T>
struct S1 {
    T a;
    int b;
};

struct S2 {
    S1<int> a;
    S1<double> b;
};

void cb(auto*);

// Many things have been tried
template<T<U>>
template<template<typename U> typename T>
void caller(T<U>*, void (*)(U*));

template<S1<T>>
void caller(S1<T>*, void (*)(T*));

template<T>
void caller<S1<T>>(S1<T>*, void (*)(T*));
```

Comment: It's hard for me to understand the question, since you're using non-standard terminology. What is "type-match"? What is a "container"? (normally "container" means something like `std::vector`, but not in your question) What is a "type variable"? What does *"bind type variables to both the container and the variable"* mean?

Comment: Fixed typo. I want to pass an `S1` pointer `s1` and `cb` to `caller` such that the type of `cb` is inferred from the type of `s1->a`. Basically I want to use a type and the type of its member to create a dependency between the `caller` parameters. Feel free to fix my terminology but I'm pretty sure the answer below nailed it. I'm a bit surprised that the answer requires an intermediate template partial specialization. Why can' the `caller` template have access to all the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `caller`'s template list should be

```
template <typename T>
struct S1 {
  T a;
  int b;
};

void cb(auto*);

template<template<typename...> typename Temp, typename U>
void caller(Temp<U>*, void (*)(U*));

int main() {
  S1<int> a;
  caller(&a, cb);

  S1<double> b;
  caller(&b, cb);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oWh3dzWhf)

Comment: Very nice, I think - I'll try running it tomorrow. Can you explain why `template_type` can access `U` while caller can't, at least in my attempts above? What did I do incorrectly? I'm trying to understand why the intermediate `template_type` is required.

Comment: @user19087 "*Can you explain why template_type can access U while caller can't, at least in my attempts above?*" In fact, your attempt is right, but your template list is wrong, see my update.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I see what I did wrong - trying to specify the relationship between `Temp` and `U` in the `<template>` rather than the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass an `S1` pointer `s1` and `cb` to caller such that the type of `cb` is inferred from the type of `s1->a`

Like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct S1 {
    T a;
    int b;
};

template <typename T>
void caller(S1<T> *, void (*)(std::type_identity_t<T> *)) {}

int main()
{
    S1<int> s1;
    caller(&s1, [](int *){});
}
```

Here `type_identity_t` is needed to stop `T` from being deduced from the second argument, which confuses the compiler when passing a lambda.